# Hide element if no child elements exist

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor, ionic4, ng-show

I am trying to find a solution for the following case:

I have a list of items which I want to filter by searching items
[image: List of items]

However it remains showing the divider elements:

[image: Dividers remain]

The code I'm running:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title *ngIf="!isOn">Events</ion-title>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="terms" *ngIf="isOn"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <button (click)="toggleDetails()">
        <ion-icon name="ios-search" size="large"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button (click)='onDismiss()'>
        <ion-icon name="options" size="large"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content *ngIf='userReady'>
  <div *ngIf='months_filtered'>
    <ion-item-group *ngFor="let month of months_filtered; let i = index">
      <ion-item-divider sticky color="secondary" lines="none">
        <ion-text>
          <h4>{{ getMonthName(i) }}</h4>
        </ion-text>
      </ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let event of month  | search : terms">
        {{ event.title }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

How can I hide the dividers and show a text "no results found" when there are no `<ion-item>` to be displayed instead?

Comment: The logic should go in your 'toggleDetails' function. You need to filter months from months_filtered collection. Please give a try yourself or provide js code of this function for us to help.

Comment: @AdityaBhave the `toggleDetails` only contains 


  toggleDetails() {
    this.isOn = !this.isOn;
  }

Answer (score 0):

You may try with an `*ngIf="month && month.length"` in the `<ion-item-divider>` like this:

```
<div *ngIf='months_filtered'>
    <ion-item-group *ngFor="let month of months_filtered; let i = index">
      <ion-item-divider sticky color="secondary" lines="none" *ngIf="month && month.length">
        <ion-text>
          <h4>{{ getMonthName(i) }}</h4>
        </ion-text>
      </ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let event of month  | search : terms">
        {{ event.title }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
  </div>
```